# Why does closing a window in Indesign doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have a question concerning Indesign script.

Why does it work, when you close a window like:

```
submitButton.onClick = function(){
    close();
}
```

But when I try to execute a function afterwards like:

```
submitButton.onClick = function(){
    close();
    tagElements();
}
```

(note I am using the "with" tag, so no `window.close()` is needed)

The window does not close? Am I forgetting about something here? Shouldn't the window close, and then execute the function?

The window is initialized like:

```
var de = new Window('dialog', 'Descriptions');
```

Comment: It should work. Could you also link include the code for the function `tagElements();`? Does the function `tagElements();` work if you only execute that function on the button click?

Comment: It does not, because functions can not be executed while a dialog is open in indesign. So the dialog has to be closed first.

Comment: The issue does not seem easily replicated, partly due to the scattered snippets of code. For example, there is no `with` in the code shown (you *say* you use it; but maybe you are using it wrong!). Can you add one single [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still has the problem?

Comment: @Frederik Witte: did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following has done the trick:

```
with(de)
    submitButton.onClick = function(){
        close(1);
     }
}
if(de.show){
    tagElements();
}
```

de.show will be true, when you pass '1' in the close function( 1 == true). On you close button you would just add 'close()' and the if statement will be false.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `close()` with `de.close()` should do the trick. This works for me;

```
var de = new Window('dialog', 'Descriptions');
btn = de.add('button', undefined, 'close');  
btn.onClick = function() {  
    de.close();
    alert('foo');
}
de.show();
```

Comment: As you can read in my post, I am using the "with" tag. No "de" reference needed

Comment: @Frederik: after moving everything inside a `with(de)` and removing the `de.`s inside, this still works. Does it not for you?

Comment: No. Define "working", please. When the alert pops up, is the dialog window still shown? Because this is the issue here

Comment: Can you show your complete code including the `with` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add a delay after closing (not tried):

```
function pause(msec) { 
  var done = null; 
  var date = new Date(); 
  var curDate = null; 
  do curDate = new Date(); 
  while(curDate-date < msec); 
  var done = 1; 
  return done; 
} 

submitButton.onClick = function(){
    close();
    pause(500);
    tagElements();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference to the Opened window in the code.

```
submitButton.onClick = function(){
de.close();
tagElements();
}
```

should work

Comment: As you can read in my post, I am using the "with" tag. No "de" reference needed